# Не работает экшен в yii2

Tags: yii2

Есть экшен `public function actionPost($postId) {/* some code */}` контроллера `site` при вызове которого (uri: `site/post`) срабатывает ошибка `Missing required parameters: postId`, что логично. Но при передаче этого параметра (через гет `site/post/1`) срабатывает `Not Found (#404)`. В чём загвоздка?

Comment: site/post/postId/1 пробовали?

Comment: @Kison да, не работает

Comment: а в конфиге `UrlManager` настроен соответственным образом для таких ссылок?

Comment: Код в студию. Как отправляете пост запрос?

Comment: @Blacknife  `'request' => [ 'baseUrl' => '' ], 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [],
        ]`

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade экшн должен получать из GET id поста и выводить его. Никаких POST данных я не отправляю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в `rules` правило

```
'site/post/<postId:\d+>' => 'site/post'
```

Comment: согласен, работает, но и без этой записи должно запускатся

Comment: @СергейО нет, не должно. Дефолтный роутинг триммит слеши в начале и в конце роута, и ищет полное соответствие по правилу <controller>/<action> либо <module>/<controller>/<action>. Т.е. ваш роут `site/post/1` стандартным роутером распознан не будет, если только у вас нет модуля `site` с контроллером `post` и экшеном `1`

Comment: @СергейО чтобы передать параметр со стандартным роутингом вам нужно делать вызов `/site/post?postId=1` тогда все будет работать и без дополнительного правила

Comment: оу, я понял... спасибо